# Are exported functions guaranteed to be instantiated once?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Are exported functions guaranteed to be instantiated once? As in, the browser will cache them, and every object or function that calls an imported function will be calling the same instance of it?

Example:

```js
export function generateIdIncrementer(string) {
  let num = 0;
  return () =>{
    return string+(num += 1);
  };
}

export const nextLayerId = generateIdIncrementer('layer-');
```

Example usage would be: file1 and file2 both import `nextLayerId`, and both files call it once. The expected outcome is that file1 will get `layer-1`, whereas file2 gets `layer-2`.

Do all modern browsers guarantee that "nextLayerId" will exist as just a single instance? Are there any scenarios where this code could potentially break from the intended behaviour?

Comment: The ECMAScript specification specifies that a module file is only evaluated once.

Comment: It's not the exported function that is instantiated only once. It's the entire module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

As I know, the `nextLayerId` you imported are the same function which owns the same reference of `num`. That's why the file1 gets 'layer-1' while file2 gets 'layer-2'.

However, if there is

```js
export const otherLayerId = generateIdIncrementer('layer-');
```

Then, the `num` referenced by `otherLayerId` is different from `nextLayerId`. And if you import `otherLayerId` from file1 and file2 and run it you will get another `layer-1` and `layer-2` instead of `layer-3` and `layer-4`.